# How to O_CLOEXEC pipes on MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, pipe, posix, system-calls

Since `pipe2` does not exist in MacOS, is the only solution to simply call `pipe`, keep track of the `pipe` file descriptors, and `close` them before an `exec` call? I am writing a program where I don't want to `close` all file descriptors past 0, 1, 2 when passing to children and don't want to leak `pipe` file descriptors specifically into children unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

Use `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)`:

```c
int fd[2];
int r = pipe(fd);
/* check r for errors */
r = fcntl(fd[0], F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
/* check r for errors */
r = fcntl(fd[1], F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
/* check r for errors */
```

Comment: Note, though, that `assert()` is horrible for error checking.  First, blowing up the entire process with a call to `abort()` and potentially causing data loss or other problems is overkill for handling something like "too many open files", and second, `assert()` completely disappears if compiled with `NDEBUG` defined, leaving your code with ZERO error checking.  Neither of "blow up the entire process!" or "ignore it entirely!" are usually appropriate error responses.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm open to suggestions that fit in a one-liner. I didn't want to make it a comment `/* check r for errors */`.

Comment: Fitting in a one-liner in no way makes `assert` suitable for checking for runtime failures.  It is for verifying invariants your program assumes.  If ever an assertion fails, it means that your program is wrong -- either your program is making an invalid assumption, or you are using assert wrongly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am _still_ open to suggestions.

Comment: `if (r != 0) return errno;` is a one-liner.

Comment: For macOS and Linux, consider using the functions from `<err.h>` ([`err(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html)).

Comment: `if (r != 0) { perror("fcntl: setting FD_CLOEXEC"); }` (`pipe()` failing probably needs more then just a diagnostic message though)

Comment: @Siguza *I'm open to suggestions that fit in a one-liner.*  **WHY** are you restricting error checking to "a one-liner"?  Is ensuring the robust, proper operation of your code so unimportant to you that you abandon efforts to do so if it takes more than one line of code?

Comment: Fine, I removed the `assert()` and delegated it to the reader to implement error handling. None of you seem to understand that this isn't the point of the question. If people want to know about error handling, they can ask a separate question, or look at the thousands of duplicates that already answer that. Moreover, it's not possible to do robust and proper error handling in a snippet like this, because in order to be proper and robust, it needs to be integrated with the rest of the codebase. There is no "one size fits all" when it comes to error handling, especially in C.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you are asking about the `O_CLOEXEC` file flag (close on `exec` system call) but you explaiin your scenario in relation to `pipe`s.  What are you asking about, exactly.  Can you further explain in your question?

Answer (score 0):

`O_CLOEXEC` is unrelated to the `pipe()` feature, nor it has something to anything but the `exec()` group of system calls.  Any file descriptor used with this flag will be closed while executing a `exec()` system call.

It's not clear what relationship it has with your explanation.  Pipes are normal file descriptors and you can `O_CLOEXEC` them by means of the `fcntl(2)` system call.  And remember, the `exec(2)` system call does not create a new process, it is the `fork()` system call, so no file descriptor is closed when creating a subprocess, but when loading a new program in the virtual space of a process.  The flag only allows you to conserve the descriptors open in case the `exec(2)` call fails (something you cannot do if you have closed them before the call to exec)

I don't fully understand why do you need the `pipe2(2)` functionality on this context, and I'm a bit confused of knowing that the Mac has no `pipe2(2)` system call, as it claims to be posix compliant (IMHO pipe2 is included in posix) and also Mac OS is a derivative work from BSD system, which has it implemented.

If, on the other way, you need to create the pipe descriptor using the flag, then you can, after creagint the descriptor, use the `fcntl(2)` system call to set that flag.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
...
    int res = fcntl(the_pipe[0], F_SETFD, O_CLOEXEC);
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("O_CLOEXEC");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

I only recommend you to use the flag with `fcntl()` (except if there's some race condition that affects your code) because specifying it in the `pipe2()` system call will affect the two file descriptors returned, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: This code works neither on macOS nor Linux. You need `F_SETFD`, not `F_SETFL`. You're also wrong about `pipe2`: it appears nowhere in the POSIX standard, and [the Linux manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe2) says it's Linux-specific, while [the NetBSD manpage](https://man.netbsd.org/pipe2.2) says it's "inspired from Linux".

Comment: Had you look at the FreeBSD page, it says it's implemented since FreeBSD v.10.0  Thanks for the downvote.  Just from a BSD user :)  I had no mac so I tried to check (from a colleague) to test if it has the `pipe2(2)` system call, without success.  If you, instead of punishing people downvoting them are so smart, you would probably could give a correct answer, with no need to punishing anybody.  Or  you will end alone in StackOverflow.